# Debugging a solution with multiple projects

Tags: asp.net, debugging, iis, w3wp.exe

I am trying to debug a project I inherited. This basically consists of an ASP.NET website hosted in IIS (local IIS not express though), and a number of other projects for example a project containing the model, another project containing the Data Access, another project containing control classes etc.

I have added the ASP.NET IIS hosted website to my Visual Studio solution by Right Clicking Solution > Add > Add Existing Website ...

When I debug the website (by setting it as the startup project) from Visual Studio, it launches and works OK so for example I manage to connect to the Web Services hosted on another server, login etc etc.

However I am finding problems to hit the breakpoints on the other projects, such as XXX.Web.Model, which contains source code I need to debug.

What settings can I modify to hit the breakpoints? I tried attaching w3wp.exe but to no avail.

Comment: Are those XXX.Web.Model projects part of your solution?

Comment: Yes they all form part of the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set multiple startup projects, and for each of the projects you want to debug set it to 'Start with debugging'. To do that on the solution node in `Solution Explorer` right click and choose `Properties` then in the dialog go to the `Startup Project` tab. As shown in the image below.
[image: Solution properties in VS]

Docs are over at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2017 .